# What happens to a running docker container when a new "latest" tag Memgraph platform image is published?

Tags: docker, memgraphdb

I created a new named container for  Memgraph Platform with:

```
docker run -ti -p 3000:3000 -p 7687:7687 -p 7444:7444 --name graph-assignment-7 memgraph/memgraph-platform:latest
```

I control the container using `docker stop graph-assignment-7` and `docker start graph-assignment-7`. I do this to avoid data loss.

My question relates to how Docker handles image updates? I’m curious about what occurs to my running container when a new image tagged as latest is released for `memgraph/memgraph-platform`. Will my container automatically transition to this latest version, or do I need to manually intervene by pulling/blocking the new image and recreating the container? I actually want to prevent Docker container from being updated to the new version of Memgraph Platform.

I can't post images due to message that I get (You need at least 10 reputation to post images.) but I hope that this link will work -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZqhK.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker doesn't update your running containers automaticially. It also doesn't pull new versions of an image automatically.

To update a container, you need to kill it, pull the new image and run the image. I.e.

```
docker kill graph-assignment-7
docker rm graph-assignment-7
docker pull memgraph/memgraph-platform:latest
docker run -ti -p 3000:3000 -p 7687:7687 -p 7444:7444 --name graph-assignment-7 memgraph/memgraph-platform:latest
```

If you don't do the `docker pull`, docker will run the image that is known as `latest` on your machine. That might not be the one that is `latest` on Docker Hub.

You can get `docker run` to check for a newer version and pull it by adding the `--pull=always` option on `docker run`. The default is `--pull=missing` which only pulls the image if it is missing on your local machine. More info here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#pull

Answer (score 0):

If you would run ‘start’ for already created docker container, it doesn’t do the transition to the latest version.
But when you will run ‘run’, it does the transition to the latest version.

Comment: Interesting, so this means that "latest" actually means "latest" in the moment of creation of the container, and not in the moment when you run the container?

Comment: When you run ‘start’, image has to be already created. When you run ‘run’, you create the image

Comment: When you say 'image', you mean 'container'

Comment: Yes, you’re right. Thanks

Comment: "latest" first means "the image you have locally that has a `latest` tag".  That may be different from the image Docker Hub has tagged as `latest`, and it's possible you can have newer local images with different tags.

Comment: So local tags are "stronger" than the tags on Docker hub? Can I force to use local or remote tag? Can the local tags be invalidated? I see what @HansKilian has written in answer. I can use --pull=always. But can I see the tags before pulling?